# CMake how to transfer shell command in CMakeLists.txt into Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile, cmake

The problem: i want to echo some info when make makefile, the makefile is generated by CMakeLists.txt, and i don't want to echo the info when cmake CMakeLists.txt, what should i do?
In Makefile, the code is like this:

```
.build-pre:
    @echo
    @echo "###########################################################"
    @echo "######## Welcome to Prosim Build System ###################"
```

What should i wirte in the CMakeLists.txt so that i can get like these in MakeFile?

Comment: Have you tried `message`? https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/message.html

Comment: Some combination of `add_custom_target` and/or `add_custom_command` with setting all other targets to depend on it, so it runs first ought to work. Don't really see much point for this particular message tho, it carries no useful information pertaining to the build process.

Comment: @usr1234567, actually i want the echo info when make makefile

Comment: @DanMašek, thanks for you answer and i get what i want just now, but there were still some problem i did not understand.

Comment: @DanMašek, i can not understand what is the function and how to use them of these two functions, can you give me some examples??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`add_custom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/add_custom_target.html) function to create a dummy target that has dependencies set to all other targets causing it to be built first.

You can use the `ALL` option to make it build every time. However, you will still need to use [`add_dependencies`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/add_dependencies.html#command:add_dependencies) to make it build *before* every other target.

Finally, use the [command-line tool mode of CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/manual/cmake.1.html?highlight=cmake%20commands#command-line-tool-mode) to make it platform independent. (The `COMMENT` option of `add_custom_target` may be enough to show the message).

---

```
add_custom_target(display_intro ALL COMMAND cmake -E echo Foo)

# ....
add_executable(your_app ...)
add_dependencies(your_app display_intro)

add_library(your_lib ...)
add_dependencies(your_lib display_intro)
```

---

For convenience, you could probably wrap the `add_executable` and `add_dependencies` in a function or macro.

Comment: Thanks for your generous help( ^_^ ), actually i understand these two function properly, but i can use them to solve my task. Further more, i used only one add_custom_target(temp_target ALL) at the start of the CMakeLists.txt, and used plenty of add_custom_command and COMMAND in one add_custom_command function, is it ok to use like this?

Comment: It's difficult to judge that without seeing all the CMakeLists needed in a decent sizes project. If it solves your problem, then it's hard to complain. The need to many `add_custom_command`s is a little suspicious -- the simpler the better, and the fact your repeat yourself hints at some need of refactoring.  Personally, when I inspect the output of the build (i.e. `make` invocation), i look for warnings and errors. If this much effort was required to make the output slightly prettier, it would probably not be worth the hassle (especially with parallelized builds).

Comment: Sorry for i lost a word in "actually i understand these two function properly", i have not understand them(i.e. why CMake do not support use Shell command directly). Hope what i did can pass in my project. Thanks for your help again  ^_^.

Comment: Sorry for excuse you again, i have suffered another problem just now. The problem was: I want to use Linux command 'if[...]then;...;fi' as the COMMAND for there are some options(some variables) in my project. And i need to transfer these options when i make the Makefile so i can not use CMake command 'if' in judgment statements, what should i do?Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ChaoZhang I think you should create a new question for that. But in general, I'd make the CMake part configurable, and let it generate a Makefile (or anything else) that doesn't depend on any other external settings (like specific environment variables) and is specific for given configuration. When I need a different build config, i just run CMake again in a clean build directory, and can have multiple variants side by side.

Comment: Thanks, i would try some other way.The project i worked on exits for a long time, and there are some inappropriate places, but it is hard for me to modify.Have a nice day:)